# Not able to get the image displayed with Image.network in flutter, while trying to retrieve an image from Firestore cloud storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I currently have a problem, where I am not to show an image, that is stored in my Firestore storage, despite the fact that I can see that it has stored the right URL, and I am able to click on the link, and go right to the image.

I have my code snippets below. The first method is me uploading the images to the questions, where I am setting the various of images of the questions:

```
 Future<List<String>> _uploadImages(List<Question> questions) async {
    List<String> imageUrls = [];
    for (Question question in questions) {
      if (question.imageUrl != null) {
        try {
          http.Response response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(question.imageUrl!));
          Uint8List imageData = response.bodyBytes;
          String imageName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
          String imagePath = 'quiz_images/$imageName.jpg';
          storage.Reference imageRef =
          storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(imagePath);
          await imageRef.putData(imageData, storage.SettableMetadata(
              contentType: 'image/jpeg'));
          String downloadUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
          imageUrls.add(downloadUrl);
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error uploading image: $e');
          imageUrls.add(''); // Add empty URL if upload fails
        }
      } else {
        imageUrls.add(''); // Add empty URL for questions without images
      }
    }
    return imageUrls;
  }
```

Later on I create a quiz, where each of these images are correctly being placed on the right indexes in my Firestore, and with my print line, I can see that it is the right URL that is being put in my document field.

```
  
  Future<void> createQuiz(Quiz quiz) async {
    try {
      User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (user == null) {
        throw Exception('User not authenticated');
      }
      DocumentReference quizRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quizzes').doc();
      quiz.id = quizRef.id;
      List<String> imageUrls = await _uploadImages(quiz.questions);
      for (int i = 0; i < quiz.questions.length; i++) {
        Question question = quiz.questions[i];
        if (question.imageUrl != null) {
          question.imageUrl = imageUrls[i];
          print(question.imageUrl);
        }
      }
      await quizRef.set(quiz.toMap());
      String displayName = await getUserDisplayName(user.uid);
      await quizRef.update({'authorDisplayName': displayName});

      print(quiz);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating quiz: $e');
    }
  }
```

Then I try to display the image, with Image.network wit the following code:

```
child: Image.network(
                  quizProvider.currentQuestionImage(questionNumber.data) ?? '',
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                )
```

I don't think that the provider method is relevant to the question, since it is just a way for me to store the imageUrl. I am able to print out the right imageUrl, but I am getting the following error message when i try to display the image:

ImageCodeException: Failed to detect image file format using the file header. File header was [0x3c 0x21 0x44 0x4f 0x43 0x54 0x59 0x50 0x45 0x20], image source: http://localhost:59725

Which confuses me, since I have triple checked that the Url is correct. Do note that I am running the flutter app in web.

Thanks in advance for any help.